# Create the same subfolders in another folder

Tags: mkdir

I have a directory `foo` with subdirectories. I wish to create the same subdirectories names in another directory without copying their content. How do I do this?

Is there a way to get `ls` output as a brace expansion list?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this,

```
cd /source/dir/path
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p -- /destination/directory/{} \;
```

- `. -type d` To list directories in the current path recursively.
- `mkdir -p -- /destination/directory/{}` create directory at destination.

This relies on a `find` that supports expanding `{}` in the middle of an argument word.

Comment: This may break if any file or folder name in the top level begins with a dash. It also omits directories that begin with a dot. Finally, be aware that not every implementation of `find` supports the interpolation of `{}` into another string.

Comment: And it is not very scalable - it will take plenty of time if there are millions of directories.

Comment: If there are many _things_ in `/source/dir/path`, then this might fail with an "argument list too long" error when the shell tries to call `find` with the expansion of `*`. Better to just use `.` there.  Also, most `find` implementations allows `{}` to be used even when concatenated with another string, but it's not universal.

Comment: You can use `.` Instead of `*` in this case. (Using xarg for performance and security would probably require an external script for the path concatenation)

Answer (score 24):

Using `rsync`:

```
rsync -a --include='*/' --exclude='*' /some/path/dir/ dir
```

This would recreate the directory structure of `/some/path/dir` as `dir` in the current directory, without copying any files.

Any directory encountered in the source path would be created at the target due to the inclusion pattern, but anything else would be excluded.  As a side effect of using `-a` (`--archive`), you'll get the same timestamps on all subdirectories in the target as in the source.  This also works for creating local directory structures from remote directories (and vice versa).

Answer (score 8):

You can use `find` to traverse the source structure and call `mkdir` for each directory it meets.

This example, using `find`, will copy your directory structure from `foo` to `/tmp/another/`

```
( cd foo && find -type d -exec sh -c 'for d do mkdir -p "/tmp/another/$d"; done' sh {} + )
```

The `exec` loop builds up the set of directories underneath `foo`, which is then passed to the `mkdir`. If you don't have a version of `find` that understands `+` you can use `\;` at the cost of efficiency. Substitute `mkdir` with `echo mkdir` to see what would happen without actually doing it.

Comment: exactly with GNU find (4.7.0-git) this doesn't seem to work: `find: In ‘-exec ... {} +’ the ‘{}’ must appear by itself, but you specified ‘/tmp/another/{}’` (it does work with `-exec ... \;`, though)

Comment: Ilkkachu I'm sure I tested `/path/to/{}` but I now can't find any version where it works so I've adapted the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

With the bash shell, you could ask it for the expansion of every directory with the `globstar` option:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

and then copy the directories with a loop:

```
for dir in **/
do
  mkdir -p /path/to/dest/"$dir"
done
```

... or if you thought they'd all fit within one call to `mkdir`:

```
set -- **/
mkdir -- "${@/#//path/to/dest/}"
```

That's bash array syntax that says: "take every element of the `$@` array and replace the beginning of each of them with `/path/to/dest/`.

I'm not aware of a way to get `ls` to output directly as a brace expansion list. If you tried to massage the output of the `**/` expansion into a brace expansion, you would need to be careful to:

- escape any commas in the output
- escape any `{` or `${` sequence
- ensure the resulting string didn't exceed the available command-line argument space

I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a cross-site duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1389580/copy-directory-structure-only-at-year-end

This kind of task is a classic use case for `mtree`:

```
$ mkdir new-tree
$ mtree -cp old-tree | mtree -tdUp new-tree
.:      modification time (Tue Sep 24 14:27:07 2019, Tue Sep 24 16:34:57 2019, modified)
./bar missing (created)
./bar/bar2 missing (created)
./bar/bar2/bar3 missing (created)
./bar/bar2/bar3/bar4 missing (created)
./foo missing (created)
./foo/foo2 missing (created)
./foo/foo2/foo3 missing (created)
```

The above creates all the directories under `new-tree` that were present under `old-tree`.  `mtree` does not set timestamps on newly-created directories, however, so the resulting tree looks like this:

```
$ find old-tree new-tree -ls
 20147  1 drwx--x---   4 jim   jim   5 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree
 20048  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   4 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/foo
 20363  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/foo/file
 20073  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   4 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/foo/foo2
 20074  1 drwx--x---   2 jim   jim   3 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/foo/foo2/foo3
 20365  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/foo/foo2/foo3/file
 20364  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/foo/foo2/file
 20051  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   4 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar
 20077  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   4 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar/bar2
 20368  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar/bar2/file
 20078  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   4 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar/bar2/bar3
 20369  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar/bar2/bar3/file
 20079  1 drwx--x---   2 jim   jim   3 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar/bar2/bar3/bar4
 20370  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar/bar2/bar3/bar4/file
 20366  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar/file
 20362  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/file
134489  1 drwx--x---   4 jim   jim   4 Sep 24 16:34 new-tree
134490  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   3 Sep 24 16:34 new-tree/bar
134491  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   3 Sep 24 16:34 new-tree/bar/bar2
134492  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   3 Sep 24 16:34 new-tree/bar/bar2/bar3
134493  1 drwx--x---   2 jim   jim   2 Sep 24 16:34 new-tree/bar/bar2/bar3/bar4
134494  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   3 Sep 24 16:34 new-tree/foo
134495  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   3 Sep 24 16:34 new-tree/foo/foo2
134496  1 drwx--x---   2 jim   jim   2 Sep 24 16:34 new-tree/foo/foo2/foo3
```

If you prefer to have the `new-tree` timestamps match those in `old-tree`, simply run `mtree` again.  Since the directories already exist, `mtree` will modify the timestamps to match the source specification:

```
$ mtree -cp old-tree | mtree -tdUp new-tree
.:      modification time (Tue Sep 24 14:27:07 2019, Tue Sep 24 16:34:57 2019, modified)
bar:    modification time (Tue Sep 24 14:27:07 2019, Tue Sep 24 16:34:57 2019, modified)
bar/bar2: 
        modification time (Tue Sep 24 14:27:07 2019, Tue Sep 24 16:34:57 2019, modified)
bar/bar2/bar3: 
        modification time (Tue Sep 24 14:27:07 2019, Tue Sep 24 16:34:57 2019, modified)
bar/bar2/bar3/bar4: 
        modification time (Tue Sep 24 14:27:07 2019, Tue Sep 24 16:34:57 2019, modified)
foo:    modification time (Tue Sep 24 14:27:07 2019, Tue Sep 24 16:34:57 2019, modified)
foo/foo2: 
        modification time (Tue Sep 24 14:27:07 2019, Tue Sep 24 16:34:57 2019, modified)
foo/foo2/foo3: 
        modification time (Tue Sep 24 14:27:07 2019, Tue Sep 24 16:34:57 2019, modified)
$ find old-tree new-tree -ls
 20147  1 drwx--x---   4 jim   jim   5 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree
 20048  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   4 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/foo
 20363  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/foo/file
 20073  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   4 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/foo/foo2
 20074  1 drwx--x---   2 jim   jim   3 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/foo/foo2/foo3
 20365  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/foo/foo2/foo3/file
 20364  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/foo/foo2/file
 20051  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   4 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar
 20077  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   4 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar/bar2
 20368  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar/bar2/file
 20078  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   4 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar/bar2/bar3
 20369  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar/bar2/bar3/file
 20079  1 drwx--x---   2 jim   jim   3 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar/bar2/bar3/bar4
 20370  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar/bar2/bar3/bar4/file
 20366  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/bar/file
 20362  1 -rw-------   1 jim   jim   0 Sep 24 14:27 old-tree/file
134489  1 drwx--x---   4 jim   jim   4 Sep 24 14:27 new-tree
134490  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   3 Sep 24 14:27 new-tree/bar
134491  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   3 Sep 24 14:27 new-tree/bar/bar2
134492  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   3 Sep 24 14:27 new-tree/bar/bar2/bar3
134493  1 drwx--x---   2 jim   jim   2 Sep 24 14:27 new-tree/bar/bar2/bar3/bar4
134494  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   3 Sep 24 14:27 new-tree/foo
134495  1 drwx--x---   3 jim   jim   3 Sep 24 14:27 new-tree/foo/foo2
134496  1 drwx--x---   2 jim   jim   2 Sep 24 14:27 new-tree/foo/foo2/foo3
```